# Reverse String Using Regexes

Tags: php, regex, string, reverse

If I had a string like `<start_delim>asdf<end_delim>` and I wanted to take an alphanumeric string between the delimiters and reverse it using regexes, how would I go about doing this?

My natural instinct was to use something like `preg_replace("<start_delim>([a-zA-Z0-9]+)<end_delim>", strrev($1), $str)`, but for obvious reasons, that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$str = "<start_delim>asdf<end_delim>";
function my_callback($m) {
  return $m[1].strrev($m[2]).$m[3];
}
echo preg_replace_callback("/(<start_delim>)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(<end_delim>)/", 'my_callback' , $str);
```

http://codepad.org/xP2arFZk

Comment: @nikic you spoke too soon... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738798/reverse-string-using-regexes/4739241#4739241

Comment: @Daniel: Uhm :( Shouldn't have mentioned it... @rubber boots: Slow, potentially insecure.

Comment: Didn't know about this callback thing; this should make other code a good deal easier, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous solutions, but using a lambda:

```
$str = "<start_delim>asdf<end_delim>";
$result = preg_replace_callback('/<start_delim>([a-zA-Z0-9]+)<end_delim>/', function($matches) {
        return strrev($matches[1]);
}, $str);

echo "$result\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Somebody pointed out in a comment it'd be better not to use the /e modifier, but 
if possible, that would work. Almost exactly as you thought:

```
echo preg_replace('|<start_delim>([^<^]+)<end_delim>|e', 'strrev("$1")', $str);
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: It would work, but it's potentially dangerous and slow - just like `eval()`.

Comment: @Alix Axel: you'd have to weight it (it's potential danger) against code cluttering and lost simplicity. IMHO there'd be some areas where it's useful and others where it's not.
   
Regards, rbo

Comment: Having code being evaluated dynamically is not *simplicity*, at least for me.

Comment: This code is vulnerable: try to run it with `$str='<start_delim>${${phpinfo()}}<end_delim>';`. You must not use double quoted strings in an eval'ed string. What makes the "e" modifier dangerous is that most will don't notice this.